# Is it mandatory for companies to patch security vulnerabilities?

Tags: france, security

I read that the Cybersecurity and Infrastructure Security Agency (CISA) often issue orders to federal agencies to patch certain vulnerabilities.

I was wondering if there are similar laws in France and if they are aimed at government agencies, so called "operator of vital importance" (OIV) or all companies.

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but your title says "companies" and your question refers to "government agencies".

Comment: My question refer to companies but I am open to see if there is also laws for government agencies.

Comment: The GDPR applies in France, and GDPR requires "technical organisational measures" to safeguard data. Failure to apply appropriate protection could result in a fine, but I'm not aware of any fine for the absence of *specific* patches. In fact, TOM are allowed to take cost-benefit-analysis into account.